# ionic app not loading updated html when using iframe

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an html page in ionic that loads another html file from S3 using iframe.  my ionic html looks like this:

```
<ion-view view-title={{header1}}>
<div class="item item-divider item-{{colorTheme}}">Privacy policy</div>
<ion-content class="padding has-header">
    <iframe ng-src="http://backoffice.taralets.com.ph.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/partials/partial-privacyPolicy.html" 
            style="height:100%; width:100%;overflow:hidden;" 
            height="100%" 
            width="100%"></iframe> 
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

After my initial testing, the html file from S3 is being displayed correctly.  Here is the html file in S3:

```
<div class="text-left">
<h2>Privacy Policy</h2>
<p>Apps Privacy Policy</p>    
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that when I change the content of the html file in s3 - say change "Apps Privacy Policy" to "This is a Privacy Policy", the display in my ionic app is still showing the original content "Apps Privacy Policy".  I am debugging this in the browser using ionic serve.  Even if I clear the Application site data when doing "inspect" in chrome, the problem still exists.  Is there a cache somewhere that's causing this problem?  Note that if I try to access the page from our website, it is reflecting the updated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code for disabling cache for the specific page

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
```

you can disable caching globally by using

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

in your configurations

Comment: tried this but it doesn't seem to work when I replace the html file with an updated version.  I can still see the old version of the html file.  What I tried is to change the <ion-view cache-view="false">  as I don't want to set it globally.

Comment: what I noticed is that when I clear the cache in the application manager, the problem still exists but if I clear the application data, the problem disappears.  Does ionic saves the iframe in the local storage of the app?

Comment: Check this url and see if it works for you. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clear-iframe-cache/31207

Comment: yes.  I was hoping to avoid doing that but it seems it might be the solution for now.  thanks.